# Finder stacked icons in icon view causes finder to crash

Tags: macos, finder, crash, icon

I have 2,260 photos in my Dropbox Camera Uploads folder. Somehow they all got stacked on top of each other. When the camera upload is complete, it launches the camera uploads folder in finder in this stacked view. This pretty much instantly brings my computer to a halt and crashes finder. I have tried refreshing every plist and cache I could find to get finder to "forget" this stacked view to no avail.

[image: stacked icons in icon view]

How do I get finder to completely forget all of it's "remembered" view preferences?

Comment: Go into Dropbox through the web interface and create a few folders in the Camera Uploads folder. Divide up the photos into these folders, then see if your Mac stays sane when you open Camera Uploads in the Dropbox app.

Comment: This should cause the files to no longer be stacked. Go into Terminal and copy/paste the following command: `rm -rf "/Users/$(whoami)/Dropbox/Camera Uploads/.DS_Store"` This is assuming you have your Dropbox folder at it's default location in your home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tubedogg has mentioned, it is the `.DS_Store` which stores the information related how the Finder formats a particular folder's view.  By deleting the `.DS_Store` file using Terminal.app, you will reset the view options of that folder.

However, if you are not comfortable using the terminal, you can go to Finder, and open a new window from the File menu: `File > New Finder Window`.

Now, click on your home folder in the sidebar, and then set the window view to `column mode` by clicking the button shown in the following screenshot, or by going to the `View` menu and selecting `As Columns`.

[image: Column Mode]

Navigate to your camera uploads folder, and select one of the images in the folder, just to make sure that the `Camera Uploads` folder is selected.  Next, from the `View` menu, change some view parameters, such as `Arrange By`, and then change the view to `List` (all this is just so that the `.DS_Store` file gets overwritten with new changes)

No guarantee that it will work, but it's worth a shot.

---

Having said all that, the simplest way to reset it is just to simply use the terminal command that tubedogg suggested. However: I would recommend against the `-rf`. There is no need for the `force & recursive` flags.  It just adds extra risk if something were to be mistyped. I'd suggest the following:

```
rm "/Users/$(whoami)/Dropbox/Camera Uploads/.DS_Store"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I swear I have deleted the .DS_Store in an attempt to solve this issue before and it didn't work. But it did work this time. I deleted the .DS_Store and then restarted finder and the issue went away. I'll report back if it reoccurs!

Comment: Hey, glad it worked out for you!